# How can I programmatically rotate a background?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, scenebuilder

I want to make an attitude indicator in JavaFX like this:

[image]

As you can see, the only thing that moves is the background. But how can I rotate the background?

I think I should rotate inserting the image in a canvas. I'm using scene builder and FXML. How can I rotate the background in Z like this in the canvas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a `StackPane`, and the pane in the front has a transparency set, then you can apply effects to the one in the back (i.e. the moving part).

```
backPane.setRotateAxis(Rotate.Z_AXIS);
backPane.setRotate(degrees);
```

This is a simple effect, with no animation. For animating the whole thing, you'll have to use a `Timeline` + `KeyFrame` and `KeyValue` (look up examples), OR use the `RotateTransition` directly (JavaFX 2.x). For the later solution, use `setCamera(new PerspectiveCamera())` on the scene.

Comment: Ok, I have the background image in a stackpane. But If I move it i see  white parts, like moving the image without the stackpane. I should maximize the image to have not visible parts and then when it turns don't see white parts. But I can't.